# How can I monitor an external request in New Relic's external-services page?

Tags: java, playframework, newrelic

I'm using the `WSRequest` class to make requests to an external web-service in my Play web-application.

Here's a small snippet of the code I'm using to make SOAP calls:

```
    WSRequest req = WS.url("http://mydomain.com/soap");
    req.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
    Map<String, Object> args = new HashedMap();
    args.put("countryCode", countryCode);
    req.body(requestTemplate.render(args));
    HttpResponse res = req.post();
    Document document=null;
    try{
        document = res.getXml();
    }catch(RuntimeException e){
        System.out.println(res.getString());
        throw e;
    }
```

I'd like SOAP calls made to this endpoint to show up on the ["External Services"](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/features/metric-types#External_services) page of New Relic. How can I instrument my code in order to accomplish this? I haven't been able to find much information about this in the documentation except for a Ruby example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this time, the New Relic Java agent only notices external calls made with the following methods:

- HttpURLConnection
- CommonsHttp
- Jets3t
- S3
- AsyncHttpClient

The Play WS API is not among those and, at this time, there is no way to for the user to do anything to modify the behavior.

I would recommend contacting New Relic tech support with a feature request to add external call support for Play's WS API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Luke. It would be great if you could leave a message about where I could file a ticket for a feature-request.

Comment: Users cannot make feature requests but tech support can on your behalf.  Just visit support.newrelic.com and make a support request.

Comment: which version of CommonsHttp is supported?

we're using org.apache.httpcomponents httpclient 4.3.2 and not seeing External Services calls

note from here: https://hc.apache.org

"HttpClient is a HTTP/1.1 compliant HTTP agent implementation based on HttpCore. It also provides reusable components for client-side authentication, HTTP state management, and HTTP connection management. HttpComponents Client is a successor of and replacement for Commons HttpClient 3.x. Users of Commons HttpClient are strongly encouraged to upgrade."

Comment: Play WS API is an async wrapper around AsyncHttpClient, so it should notice these calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can now implement custom network tracking:
https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/mobile-sdk-api/android-api#track-custom